# PHPmailer not connecting to office365 SMTP

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I have a script that uses phpmailer to send emails via office 365 smtp. It had been working for the last year or so. Now I'm getting an error connecting to the server.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Parishes_staging\ChristTheKing\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php:1898
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Parishes_staging\ChristTheKing\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1725): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array)
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Parishes_staging\ChristTheKing\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1481): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Fri, 14 F...', 'This is a multi...')
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Parishes_staging\ChristTheKing\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1320): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend()
#3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Parishes_staging\ChristTheKing\submitform2.php(195): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send()
#4 {main}
thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Parishes_staging\ChristTheKing\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php on line 1898
```

The script is as follows:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username = "user@company.org";                 
$mail->Password = "password";                           
$mail->SetFrom('sentfromemail@company.org', 'FromEmail');
//$mail->addAddress('user@company.org', 'ToEmail');
$mail->addAddress('user2@company.org', 'ToEmail');
$mail->addBCC('user2@company.org', 'ToBCCEmail');
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 3;
$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {echo "debug level $level; message: $str";}; 
$mail->Debugoutput = 'echo';
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Parish Registration Form';
$mail->Body    = $body;
$mail->AltBody = $body;

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

I've searched the internet for the connection settings associated with Office 365 and I see nothing wrong. Did something change on the Microsoft servers that I should know about but don't?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up PHPMailer with Office365 SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947434/setting-up-phpmailer-with-office365-smtp)

Comment: Have a read of [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong on your end.

Check your firewall for port 587 blocking. If not then the issue might be from SMTP server-side. Contact Microsoft support.

Comment: I checked and the port is open. is there anything else I can try before contacting Microsoft?  maybe a way to test settings with the server.

Comment: I don't think there is any issue your server.

Comment: I downloaded SocketLabs SMTP console and am able to connect and authenticate if I use the same server, port 25 and no encryption. I changed the port in my code to 25 and SMTPSecure = 'none';  the page just times out without any output.

Comment: Are you sure it's connecting to Office 365? I doubt very much that MS allows authentication without encryption.

Comment: The server uses TLS encryption but with smtp console, I had to connect no encryption then starttls after establishing a connection prior to authentication..

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a certificate error. When no certificate file is specified in php.ini the root certificate is supposed to be used. but it was not being used.

I had to add the following code to get it working:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```