# Can't send Email with Outlook SMTP using PhpMailer and Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, outlook, phpmailer

Whenever i try to send an E-mail (outlook SMTP) using: Phpmailer i get this error:

```
2020-06-05 18:45:05 Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2020-06-05 18:45:05 Connection: opened
2020-06-05 18:45:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 AM0PR10CA0059.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 5 Jun 2020 18:45:05 +0000
2020-06-05 18:45:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-AM0PR10CA0059.outlook.office365.com Hello [82.165.86.40]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-STARTTLS250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2020-06-05 18:45:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2020-06-05 18:45:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2020-06-05 18:45:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-AM0PR10CA0059.outlook.office365.com Hello [82.165.86.40]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2020-06-05 18:45:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2020-06-05 18:45:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2020-06-05 18:45:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2020-06-05 18:45:05 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2020-06-05 18:45:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2020-06-05 18:45:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [AM0PR10CA0059.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
2020-06-05 18:45:10 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [AM0PR10CA0059.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2020-06-05 18:45:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-06-05 18:45:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
2020-06-05 18:45:10 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

I tried with Codeigniter  as well

```
Failed to authenticate password. Error:
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

i tried both way but not working ...

i am using codeigniter default mail class

here is the config:

```
        $config = array(

            'smtp_crypto'  => 'tls', or 'startTls'
            'smtp_auth'  => true,
            'protocol'  => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'smtp.office365.com',
            'smtp_port' => 587,
            'smtp_timeout' => '7',
            'smtp_user' => 'email@account.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'emailPassword', or 'APPPASSWORD'
            'mailtype'  => 'html',
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
            'wordwrap'  => TRUE,
            'validation'   => TRUE
        );
```

This is the Phpmailer Config:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host     = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->Username = 'email@account.com';
$mail->Password = 'emailPassword'; or 'APPPASSWORD'
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls', or 'startTls',
$mail->Port     =  587
```

anybody faced with type of problem ?
Looking for some help !!!

Comment: It just looks like your credentials are wrong. If you’re absolutely sure they are correct, contact Outlook support, as there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: `SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful`

Comment: This line looks a little odd `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls', or 'startTls',`

Comment: Also this line `'smtp_crypto'  => 'tls', or 'startTls'`

Comment: Also this line `'smtp_pass' => 'emailPassword', or 'APPPASSWORD'`

Comment: ` 'smtp_pass' => 'emailPassword', or 'APPPASSWORD' `

i tried with emailPassword as well as Created APP Password ....

see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61359150/5356038

Answer (score 4):

I had some certificate issues and thats how I used it finally:

```
<?php
$mailusername= "******";
$mailpassword= "******";
$mailhost= "smtp.office365.com";
$to="*******";
$subject="test";
$body="abcdef";


require_once('PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php');


$mail = new PHPMailer();


$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Host       = $mailhost;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$mail->Username   = $mailusername;
$mail->Password   = $mailpassword;

$frommail = $mailusername;//$this->from;
$fromname = "Mailbot";
$mail->SetFrom($frommail, $fromname);


$address = $to;
$adrname = "";
$mail->AddAddress($address, $adrname);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    //echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    print( "sendViaSMTP() - failed to send email");
} else {
    print( "sendViaSMTP() - success sending email");
    // all good
}


?>
```

(1) For me the tricky part were the `SMTPOptions()`.

(2) The other tricky part was to use the **latest** `PHPMailer()` lib. Because the `SMTPOptions()` is only supported by newer `PHPMailer()`

(3) Using the "no-verify" option is insecure. However on some servers needed due to setup / configuration issues.

**updated my code**

I am using PHPMailer

```
   public $Version = '5.2.8';
```

Comment: No Luck...

Same Error....

`2020-06-06 19:48:36 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [AM0PR04CA0034.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com]`

Comment: you could try setting **$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";**

Comment: the updated example code should work. if not I suggest to test sending from any other email program using SMTP. because I guess your login data is incorrect or your account is not enabled to allow sending by external program.

Comment: i already fixed the problem .... 
i changed couple of thing in Office 365 Admin Console...
but thanks for your help :)

Comment: @fahimarifen I'm having the same issue trying to use office 365 as smtp server in CI, can you share what did you change in Office 365 Admin Console? Thanks

Comment: @fahimarifen yes please let me know what things you done.

Comment: @Frank did you solved your issue as well ?