# SMTP connect() failed Office 365 OVH

Tags: php, smtp, office365, phpmailer, ovh

I am using PHPMailer to send mails from website to a specific address

Here is my configuration :

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
    
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';                                       // Format d'encodage à utiliser pour les caractères

$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                                           // Valeur entre 0 (normal) et 4 (full debug). Attention : mettre cette valeur > 0 dévoule certains paramètres confidentiels !
    
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';                             // Adresse IP ou DNS du serveur SMTP
$mail->Port = 587;                                              // Port TCP du serveur SMTP (port SMTP chez OVH : 465=avec_SSL et 587=sans_SSL/avec_tls)
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;                                         // Utiliser l'authentification
    
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';  

$mail->Username   = 'email@xyz.x';                  
$mail->Password   = 'PWD';
```

I enabled and enforced the **multifactor authentication** and created an app password that i put in $mail->Password.

I still get the same erreur :

```
2023-01-09 14:32:53 Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2023-01-09 14:32:53 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to smtp.office365.com:587 (Connection refused) [/home/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line 388]
2023-01-09 14:32:53 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I tried every solution i found on google but nothing seems to work.. the website host is
** OVH **.

I tried with and without the MFA but i get the same results.. if anyone was facing the same problem and found a working solution i'd be so grateful !
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would start by [reading all this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947434/setting-up-phpmailer-with-office365-smtp) and trying some of the solutions mentioned

Comment: `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';` that value should be `tls`.